React functional component default props error
We have two React projects with two main parts: "Childs," a series of components, and "Main," a microfrontend orchestrator that loads "Childs" as a package.
I’m encountering tris bug.
In "Childs," in my grid (which uses MUI), when I click the "delete" button, it deletes a row and shows a popup message. This works fine! The message displayed is "Are you sure you want to delete ..." with two buttons: one to delete and another to cancel.
However, when I use it in "Main," it only shows a blank dialog with a button labeled "OK." In the console, I get the following error (in "Main"):
index.js:65 Warning: SoaAlertContent: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead.
at SoaAlertContent (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:309464:13)
at div
at div
at https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:21786:66
at FocusTrap (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:43930:5)
at div
at https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:21786:66
at Portal (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:45001:5)
at Modal (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:63125:82)
at SoaAlert (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:309484:13)
at SiteDeleteDialog (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:292836:29)
at div
at https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:21786:66
at HierarchyTableView (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:292615:94)
at RenderedRoute (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:278277:5)
at Routes (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:278967:5)
at Router (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:278901:15)
at BrowserRouter (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:276857:5)
at SnackbarProvider (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:200629:24)
at App (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:289617:16)
at ExtensionsProvider (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:300512:31)
at DefaultPropsProvider (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:77513:3)
at RtlProvider (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:77658:7)
at ThemeProvider (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:76337:5)
at ThemeProvider (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:77949:5)
at ThemeProvider (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:74677:14)
at Provider (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:273791:3)
at Root (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:296466:357)
at div
at class_1 (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:42017:27)
at n (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:617529:6223)
at t (https://localhost:8080/soa-root-config.js:617529:3311)

And this is how it’s showing:

Now, this is how it’s working in my "Childs" project, but I also have the same problem in the console:
Warning: SoaAlertContent: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead.
at SoaAlertContent (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:549026:13)
at div
at div
at https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:883:66
at FocusTrap (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:52819:5)
at div
at https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:883:66
at Portal (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:43209:5)
at Modal (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:40072:87)
at SoaAlert (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:549046:13)
at SiteDeleteDialog (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:391086:17)
at div
at https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:883:66
at HierarchyTableView (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:390663:66)
at RenderedRoute (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:255505:5)
at Routes (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:256206:5)
at Router (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:256140:15)
at BrowserRouter (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:254084:5)
at SnackbarProvider (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:178537:24)
at App (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:384706:20)
at ExtensionsProvider (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:540074:31)
at DefaultPropsProvider (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:57906:3)
at RtlProvider (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:58051:7)
at ThemeProvider (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:56730:5)
at ThemeProvider (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:58342:5)
at ThemeProvider (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:54057:14)
at Provider (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:251699:3)
at Root (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:397978:20)
at div
at class_1 (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:21455:27)
at n (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:618330:6223)
at t (https://localhost:8080/soa-isildur-developer-root-config.js:618330:3311)

And this is how it’s showing:

So this is my "Alert Component":

import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import { Modal, TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { UnselectableTextinDiv, UnselectableTextinP } from '../../../styles/shared/CommonStyles';
import { RoundedButton } from '../Buttons';
import { CircularProgressIndeterminate } from '../CircularProgressIndeterminate';

type AlertTextFieldProps = {
  value: string;
  onChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => void;
  maxLength?: number;
};

function AlertTextField(props: AlertTextFieldProps) {
  const { value, onChange, maxLength } = props;
  const MAX_CHARS = maxLength ?? 500;
  const inputTextLength = value?.length || 0;
  const handleOnChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    if (e.target.value.length <= MAX_CHARS) {
      onChange(e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <StyledTextField
      multiline
      rows={4}
      variant="filled"
      value={value}
      onChange={handleOnChange}
      helperText={`${inputTextLength}/${MAX_CHARS} max`}
      inputProps={{ 'data-testid': 'input-text' }}
    />
  );
}

type SoaAlertContentProps = {
  title?: string;
  text: string;
  confirmButtonText?: string;
  cancelButtonText?: string;
  onConfirmClick: () => void;
  onCancelClick?: () => void;
  testid?: string;
  isAlert?: boolean;
  flexGrow?: number;
  reverseButtonOrder?: boolean;
  children?: ReactNode;
  isLoading?: boolean;
};

/**
 * Use this SoaAlertContent for those SoaAlerts that require the basic SoaAlert with title, body and action buttons.
 * For a customized SoaAlert make use of the elements that form AlertContent (AlertWrapper, AlertText, AlertButtonBar...)
 *
 * @param title Optional.
 * @param text Main body text for the Alert
 * @param confirmButtonText  Optional. By default `Confirm`
 * @param cancelButtonText Optional. By default `Cancel`
 * @param onConfirmClick
 * @param onCancelClick Optional. If provided will render a secondary button for cancel
 * @param children Optional. If provided will render the ReactNode under text
 *
 */
function SoaAlertContent(props: SoaAlertContentProps) {
  const {
    title,
    text,
    confirmButtonText,
    cancelButtonText,
    onConfirmClick,
    onCancelClick,
    isAlert,
    flexGrow,
    children,
    reverseButtonOrder,
    isLoading
  } = props;

  return (
    <AlertWrapper data-testid={props.testid}>
      <AlertBody data-testid="soa-alert-body">
        {title && <AlertTitle data-testid="soa-alert-title">{title}</AlertTitle>}
        <AlertText data-testid="soa-alert-text">{text}</AlertText>
        {children}
      </AlertBody>
      <AlertButtonBar data-testid="soa-alert-button-bar" reverseButtonOrder={reverseButtonOrder}>
        {onCancelClick && (
          <StyledRoundedButton data-testid="cancel-button" variant="secondary" onClick={onCancelClick}>
            {cancelButtonText}
          </StyledRoundedButton>
        )}

        <StyledRoundedButton
          data-testid="confirm-button"
          onClick={onConfirmClick}
          isAlert={isAlert}
          disabled={isLoading}
          $flexGrow={flexGrow}
          $hasSpinner={isLoading}
        >
          {isLoading && <CircularProgressIndeterminate size={24} />} {confirmButtonText}
        </StyledRoundedButton>
      </AlertButtonBar>
    </AlertWrapper>
  );
}

SoaAlertContent.defaultProps = {
  confirmButtonText: 'Confirm',
  cancelButtonText: 'Cancel',
  isAlert: false
};

type SoaAlertProps = {
  open: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  disableBackdropClick?: boolean;
  children: ReactNode;
};

/**
 * SoaAlert is based on Modal form MUI. Use component AlertWrapper as a child to format the alert with
 * SoaAlert style.
 *
 * SoaAlertContent component can be used as an example to help form a SoaAlert.
 *
 * @param {boolean} open
 * @param onClose
 * @param {boolean} disableBackdropClick? If `true`, clicking on the backdrop will not close the Modal
 *
 */
function SoaAlert(props: SoaAlertProps) {
  const { children, open, onClose, disableBackdropClick } = props;
  const handleClose = (event: {}, reason: 'backdropClick' | 'escapeKeyDown') => {
    if (event) {
    }
    if ((reason === 'backdropClick' || 'escapeKeyDown') && disableBackdropClick) {
    } else {
      onClose();
    }
  };

  return (
    <Modal data-testid="soa-alert" open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
      <ModalContent>{children}</ModalContent>
    </Modal>
  );
}

export { AlertBody, AlertButtonBar, AlertText, AlertTextField, AlertTitle, AlertWrapper, SoaAlertContent };
export default SoaAlert;


And this is how the "Site delete dialog was made:

import {
  AlertBody,
  AlertWrapper,
  anyReasonValueType,
  CenteredSpinner,
  dictionary,
  SoaAlert,
  SoaAlertContent,
  useExtensionInteraction,
} from "soa-gollum";
import {
  useDeleteSiteMutation,
  useGetSubSitesQuery,
} from "../../store/api/sauron/sitesSlice";
import {
  extensionAnyReasonKeys,
  extensionNotifyTopicsKeys,
} from "../../extension";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { theme } from "soa-gollum/src/styles/theme";

const { shouldNotDeleteSite } = extensionAnyReasonKeys;

type Prop = {
  isOpen: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  id: string;
  name: string | undefined;
};

export default function SiteDeleteDialog({ id, isOpen, name, onClose }: Prop) {
  const { anyReason } = useExtensionInteraction();
  const [otherReasonsNotToDelete, setOtherReasonsNotToDelete] =
    useState<anyReasonValueType>();

  const { didDeleteSite } = extensionNotifyTopicsKeys;
  const { notify } = useExtensionInteraction();

  const { data: subSitesData, isLoading: subSitesDataLoading } =
    useGetSubSitesQuery(
      {
        siteKey: id,
      },
      { skip: !id }
    );

  const [deleteSite] = useDeleteSiteMutation({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    anyReason(shouldNotDeleteSite, { id })
      .then((reason) => {
        setOtherReasonsNotToDelete(reason);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, [id]);

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    deleteSite({
      siteKey: id,
    })
      .then(() => {
        notify(didDeleteSite, {
          body: {
            key: id,
          },
        });
        onClose();
      })
  };

  if (!id || !isOpen) {
    return <></>;
  }

  const deleteErrorMessage =
    dictionary.web.detailsPages.deleteMessageExistingSubSites;

  const deleteConfirmMessage =
    dictionary.web.detailsPages.deleteMessage.replace("{0}", name as string);

  const isSubsitesAvailable =
    subSitesData &&
    subSitesData?.length > 0 &&
    subSitesData?.some((item) => !item.deleted);

  const isDeleteNotAllowed = isSubsitesAvailable || otherReasonsNotToDelete;

  function getAlertTextMessage() {
    if (isSubsitesAvailable) return deleteErrorMessage;
    else if (otherReasonsNotToDelete) return otherReasonsNotToDelete?.message;
    else return deleteConfirmMessage;
  }

  return (
    <SoaAlert open={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
      {subSitesDataLoading || loading ? (
        <AlertWrapper>
          <AlertBody>
            <CenteredSpinner color={theme.palette.primary.main} />
          </AlertBody>
        </AlertWrapper>
      ) : (
        <div data-testid="site-delete-dialog">
          <SoaAlertContent
            text={getAlertTextMessage()}
            confirmButtonText={
              isDeleteNotAllowed
                ? dictionary.web.common.ok
                : dictionary.web.common.delete
            }
            onConfirmClick={isDeleteNotAllowed ? onClose : handleSubmit}
            cancelButtonText={dictionary.web.common.cancel}
            {...(isDeleteNotAllowed
              ? { flexGrow: 0.4 }
              : { onCancelClick: onClose, isAlert: true })}
            reverseButtonOrder={true}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </SoaAlert>
  );
}



And finally, it's used like this:

<SiteDeleteDialog
          id={selectedRowId!}
          name={selectedRowName}
          isOpen={selectedPopup === TableConstant.contextControls.delete}
          onClose={handleMoveSiteDialogClose}
        />


If any configuration of the microfrontend in the "Main" project is needed, I’d be happy to post it. Thanks for the help!
